# Quartz Scheduler Run job every 4 hours starting from 7.30 am

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule quartz job for every four hours starting from 7.30 on weekdays.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this：

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInHours(4)
        .RepeatForever())
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
        .WeeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(“Your working day”, 30, 07)
        .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central America Standard Time")))
    .ForJob(myJobKey)
    .Build();
```

For more usage, please refer to the official [documentation：https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html#simpletrigger-misfire-instructions](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html#simpletrigger-misfire-instructions)